# Flutter easy_localization and intl version solving failed

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, intl

I'm getting this error after updating `flutter` to version 1.25.0-8.1.pre-

```
Because `easy_localization` >=2.1.0+1 depends on `flutter_localizations` any from sdk which depends on `intl` 0.17.0-nullsafety.2, `easy_localization` >=2.1.0+1 requires `intl` 0.17.0-nullsafety.2.
So, because news_app depends on both `easy_localization` ^2.3.3 and `intl` ^0.16.1, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because news_app depends on both `easy_localization` ^2.3.3 and `intl` ^0.16.1, version solving failed.)
```

I have `easy_localization` 2.3.3, `intl` 0.16.0 and `dart` 2.12.0 installed. Please help

Answer (score 3):

Basically what's happening is `easy_localization` uses a package which uses a newer version of `intl`. Basically, you're asking the package manager to handle two versions of the same package, there are two solutions.

1. Downgrade `easy_localization` package to a version which uses the same intl version (not recommended)
2. Upgrade your intl version to `0.17.0-nullsafety.2` (recommended, but null safecty is still in beta so you have to be aware of that)

Have a good day!

Comment: if I do that I get other conflicts pointing to that new version, The package it complains about is my project, there is not an specific package for my error

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best way to solve this,
You need to switch your flutter channel to a stable version, by running

```
flutter channel stable
```

in the command line. This will switch your channel to a stable version and will get rid of the error.

I hope this best solves your issue.